# Populating MySQL data with Google Charts

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'd like to create a pie chart which basically should display how many tasks a student has completed out of all tasks he has been assigned to. so my table for tasks looks like this

tasks
task_id | task_student_id | task_status

*task_student_id* references the *user_id* in the students table

So lets say my sample data for student with user_id looks like this in the tasks table

task_id | task_student_id |task_status
  1              6          complete
  2              6          complete
  3              6          not_complete
  4              6          not_complete
  5              6          complete

So the pie chart for this student should display either the number of completed and not completed tasks or the percentage (i.e. 40% not complete 60%complete)

I found a tutorial online. There's two php files the first one lets you select the user_id from students table

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart,table package.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});

  function drawItems(num) {
    var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
      url: "getpiechartdata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
      url: "gettabledata.php",
      data: "q="+num,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var piechartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonPieChartData);
    var tabledata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);

    // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(piechartdata, {
      width: 700,
      height: 500,
      chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
    });

    // Instantiate and draw our table, passing in some options.
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(tabledata, {showRowNumber: true, alternatingRowStyle: true});
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <select name="users" onchange="drawItems(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a student:</option>
  <?php
    $dbuser="";
    $dbname="";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbserver="";
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Create a Query
    $sql_query = "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM students";
    // Execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<option value='. $row['user_id'] . '>'. $row['user_name'] . '</option>';
    }
    mysql_close($con);
  ?>
  </select>
  </form>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then the second php file populates the chart based on the user_id selected

```
<?php
  $q=$_GET["q"];

  $dbuser="";
  $dbname="";
  $dbpass="";
  $dbserver="";

  $sql_query = "SELECT task_status, COUNT(*) FROM tasks
    WHERE  task_student_id=" . $q . ""

  $con = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass);
  if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
  mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

  $result = mysql_query($sql_query);

    $data = array('cols' => array(array('label' => 'Not completed', 'type' => 'string'),
                              array('label' => 'Completed', 'type' => 'string')),
              'rows' => array());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(array('v' => $row[0]), array('v' => $row[1])));
}    

echo json_encode($data);



  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the arrays and the query. Also I was thinking of creating two separate sql queries and to save them in two php variables; $not_completed, $completed and populate it in the chart. Don't know which one is the best option for my question. can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://developers.google.com/chart/ to find a documentation of google charts. if you already have both variables $complete and $not_complete you can use this example http://pastebin.com/qsB0hqmJ and you should improve your mysql/php code by using mysql_result.

```
$tasks_completed = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks..."),0);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Where would I put the query in the code you sent me? Also, I should be creating two queries right? sorry, Im a beginner

Comment: you must establish the mysql connection and get the result of the queries before inserting the values (it does not matter where since php and the html output is divided). here is an example how you can manage it http://pastebin.com/tkTJQdFA